# Technological shocks and Labour supply in RBC and NK models

Tags: macroeconomics, new-keynesian-economics, rbc

In the class notes of Eric Sims on RBC and New Keynesian models, [in his site](http://www3.nd.edu/~esims1/grad_macro_16.html),  we get to see several graphs with the impulse response functions (IRF) of real variables such as output, labour hours, consumption, etc.

One thing, I don't get is why for the basic RBC (and some extensions) whenever we get a positive tech shock, the labour hours($N_t$) increases, but for the New Keynesian models $N_t$ decreases... Why is that?

Any help would be appreciated.